# Tricky 301Redirect Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want link to be redirected in a manner such that url with not slash at the end should be redirected to the url with the slash at the end.

example 1:

```
http://example.com/quiz/funny-riddles-with-answers
```

should be redirect to

```
http://example.com/quiz/funny-riddles-with-answers/
```

example 2

```
http://example.com/quiz/math-riddles-with-answers
```

should be redirected to

I have no idea how to do it.

my current screen shot of .htacess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ mypage.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules in `/quiz/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz/

# add a trailing slash for non-directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?[^/])[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ mypage.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rewrite to a trailing slash using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Place above your already existing rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your current rule's pattern to: `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$`

then add this right under `RewriteBase /quiz/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @SheldonCooper where is your htaccess file?